# Object Oriented PHP Array - Create "locations" list from OO PHP data

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm using FedEx's API to find "dropoff" locations for their stores that I then will be displaying using a map API (Google).

The API is working however I am having trouble as I am unfamiliar with the Object Oriented array.

I'd like to store values in the array as unique variables so I can pass them to my map API.

I'm trying to accomplish something LIKE the below:

```
<?php

// MY "IDEAL" solution - any other ideas welcome
// (yes, reading up on Object Oriented PHP is on the to-do list...)

$response = $client ->fedExLocator($request);

if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR')
{
    $response -> BusinessAddress -> StreetLines[0] = $location_0;
    $response -> BusinessAddress -> StreetLines[1] = $location_1;
    $response -> BusinessAddress -> StreetLines[2] = $location_2;
}

?>
```

Working FedEx Code Sample:

```
<?php

$response = $client ->fedExLocator($request);

if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR')
{
    echo 'Dropoff Locations<br>';
    echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>Streetline</td><td>City</td><td>State</td><td>Postal Code</td><td>Distance</td></tr>';
    foreach ($response -> DropoffLocations as $location)
    {
        if(is_array($response -> DropoffLocations))
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$location -> BusinessAddress -> StreetLines. '</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$location -> BusinessAddress -> PostalCode. '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo $location . Newline;
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}

?>
```

Comment: What array are you trying to store the location to? Also can you print a var_dump of a typical `$response` object?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign to the `$response` array you receive from Fedex? That is your data *source*.  You should assign those values to your own data object.

Comment: Try `$response->DropOffLocations[0]->BusinessAdress->StreetLines[0]` instead of `$response->BusinessAdress->StreetLines[0]`.

Comment: thanks...@Mike ...yes var_dump($response) and var_dump($response -> DropoffLocations) all working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, from what I can tell, the `$response` object has two members: `$response->HighestSeverity`, which is a string, and `$response->DropoffLocations`, which is an array. `$response->DropoffLocations` is *just* an array, nothing fancy about it on its face. You can refer to its entries with square brackets (e.g. `$response->DropoffLocations[0]` etc), or, as they have done, walk through it with `foreach`.

The only thing "object oriented" about the array, other than the fact that it is a member of an object, is that its entries are objects, rather than simple values.

As a result, you're putting your indexing in the wrong place (and missing `DropoffLocations` altogether). Instead of, for example, this:

```
$response -> BusinessAddress -> StreetLines[0] = $location_0;
```

You should be indexing `$response->DropoffLocations` itself, and then pulling the member variables from each entry, like this:

```
$response -> DropoffLocations[0] -> BusinessAddress -> StreetLines = $location_0;
```

Do note @PeterGluck's comment, though. It's very unlikely that you want to *set* that value to anything.

Comment: wouldn't it be `$response->DropOffLocations[0]->BusinessAdress->StreetLines` instead, because the `foreach` doesn't originate from `$response` it originates from `$response->DropOffLocations`?

Comment: @Nile: yup, just noticed, fixed.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm working through this now based on your response and everyone else's

Comment: @dabra904: Note that I had a typo (`$response[0]->DropoffLocations` instead of `$response->DropoffLocations[0]`).